# ¿Como empujar a mi jugador colisionando con un objeto en unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity2d

Estoy realizando un juego de endless runner, lo que quiero es que al momento de que el jugador toque un obstáculo, este sea empujado un poco hacia atrás.

Tengo el script de la colisión pero el momento de colisionar aparece en el punto de partida.

```html
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D obstaculo)
        {
            if (obstaculo.gameObject.tag == "Obstaculo")
            {
               transform.position = new Vector3 (-1,0,0);
            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede con tu script es que siempre que colisiona lo envias al mismo punto "new Vector3 (-1,0,0)", debes capturar la posicion en el momento de la colision y en razon a esta mover tu player en la direccion que consideras hacia atras, no un punto fijo en el mundo.

Comment: Si lo acabo de revisar y arreglar muchas gracias!